# Solana - How to get token balance for a foreign account?

Tags: blockchain, solana

In Solana you can get your own balance with the CLI

```
$ spl-token accounts
```

But how do I get the token balance of a foreign account if I have the account ID or his pubkey? When I use the solana explorer I can see the information I need when I search for the foreign account ID and then click on the Tokens tab (next to "History"):
https://explorer.solana.com/address/DNuqHBGxzm96VLkLWCUctjYW9CX68DBY6jQ1cVuYP2Ai/tokens?cluster=devnet

So if the explorer website can do it, everybody can, all info on the blockchain is public, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, everything is indeed public, so if you want to get the balance for someone else's account, you can simply use `getBalance` if it's SOL (https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getbalance) or `getTokenAccountBalance` if it's an SPL Token account (https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountbalance).

Comment: any batched operation for this function? i.e. a function that takes multiple pubkeys as input, instead of just one?

Comment: Not for this `getBalance` / `getTokenAccountBalance`, you'll instead have to use `getMultipleAccounts` with `jsonParsed` encoding, and then extract the balance from the result there: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getmultipleaccounts

Comment: where can I submit a feature request for this? xD

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues go for it!

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of foreign accounts with their balances, the following CLI command can be used:

```
$ spl-token accounts --owner <account owner's pubkey>
```

- where <account owner's pubkey> is the public key or address of the wallet you want to get the info about.

Answer (score -1):

Following code worked to get the balance for SOL after Jon Cinque's answer (maybe helpful for others or future me):

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const { Keypair, Transaction, SystemProgram, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, sendAndConfirmTransaction, clusterApiUrl } = require("@solana/web3.js");

let secretKey = Uint8Array.from([233, 65, ... (rest of my secret)]);

let fromKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);

let connection = new web3.Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'));

(async () => {

    const balance = await connection.getBalance(
        fromKeypair.publicKey
    );
    console.log(balance)
})()
```

Output: `7912350560` which is correct, since I have 7.912350560 SOL in that account.

But for the SPL Token it didn't work yet...